# Can a shared lock on a std::shared_timed_mutex be upgraded to an exclusive lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

The new std::shared_timed_mutex allows for two types of locks: shared and exclusive.

If one holds a shared lock, is there any way to atomically exchange it ("upgrade it") to an exclusive lock? In other words, given the following code, how can I avoid the non-atomic drop and re-lock?

```
std::shared_timed_mutex m; //Guards a std::vector.
m.lock_shared();

//Read from vector. (Shared lock is sufficient.)
// ...

//Now we want to write to the vector. We need an exclusive lock.
m.unlock_shared();
                   //     <---- Problem here: non-atomic! 
m.lock(); 

//Write to vector.
// ...

m.unlock();
```

Ideally, `m.unlock_shared(); m.lock();` could be replaced with something like `m.upgrade_to_exclusive();` (or something like the `boost::.upgrade_to_unique_lock()`).

[In a similar question but for Boost's shared_mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378266/upgrading-boostshared-lock-to-exclusive-lock) Dave S mentions

> It is impossible to convert from a shared lock to a unique lock, or a shared lock to an upgradeable lock without releasing the shared lock first.

I'm not certain whether this applies to std::shared_mutex, though I suspect it does.

I would be happy with a reasonable work-around based on std::atomic/condition_variable or GCC's transactional memory.

**Edit:** Howard's answer addresses my question. His [proposal N3427](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3427.html) contains nice descriptions of a mechanism to achieve mutex upgrading. I still welcome work-arounds based on std::atomic/condition_variable or GCC's transactional memory.

Comment: seems std::shared_mutex cannot, but [boost::shared_mutex can!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/989816/1067003)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, it can not.  That functionality was proposed to the committee under the name `upgrade_mutex` and `upgrade_lock`, but the committee chose to reject that portion of the proposal.  There is currently no work under way to re-prepose that functionality.

**Edit**

In response to the "where to go from here" edit in user3761401's question, I've created a partially crippled implementation of `upgrade_mutex/upgrade_lock` here:

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/upgrade_mutex

Feel free to use this.  It is in the public domain.  It is only lightly tested, and it does not have the full functionality described in [N3427](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3427.html).  Specifically the following functionality is missing:

- One can not convert a `unique_lock` to a `shared_timed_lock`.
- One can not try- or timed-convert a `shared_timed_lock` to a `unique_lock`.
- One can not try- or timed-convert a `upgrade_lock` to a `unique_lock`.

That being said, I've included this functionality in `upgrade_mutex` and it can be accessed at this low level in a very ugly manner (such examples are in main.cpp).

The other lock conversions mentioned in [N3427](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3427.html) are available.

- try- and timed-conversions from `shared_timed_lock` to `upgrade_lock`.
- conversion from `upgrade_lock` to `shared_timed_lock`.
- blocking conversion from `upgrade_lock` to `unique_lock`.
- conversion from `unique_lock` to `upgrade_lock`.

It has all been put in `namespace acme`.  Put it in whatever namespace you want.

*Requirements*

The compiler needs to support "rvalue-this" qualifiers, and explicit conversion operators.

*Disclaimers*

The code has been only lightly tested.  If you find bugs I would appreciate a pull request.

It is possible to optimize the `upgrade_mutex` through the use of `std::atomic`.  No effort has been done on that front (it is a difficult and error prone task, taking more time than I have at the moment).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I see [your proposal N3427](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3427.html), specifically the section beginning "Overview for upgrade locking" which addresses my question exactly.  Are you aware of the rationale for the rejection?

Comment: Unfortunately I missed that meeting.  So I don't know the details.  It was also proposed for C++11 in the 2007 time frame, and rejected at that time because we needed to eliminate material so that we could ship C++09 on time (which didn't happen).

Comment: @user3761401 Probably because it was desired to allow backing `shared_mutex` with a `SRWLOCK`, which does not provide that feature.

Comment: @BillyONeal:  If that was the rationale, it was naively mistaken.  `upgrade_mutex` is 100% independent of `shared_mutex`.  VS could still have a `shared_mutex` backed by `SRWLOCK` in addition to an `upgrade_mutex`.

Comment: @Howard: Oh, I see, under a different mutex type. Nevermind then

Comment: Some days I just need to keep my damn mouth shut.

Comment: @HowardHinnant was this re-proposed for c++17? It seems to me that it's a glaring hole in c++'s thread support library, and seemingly easily plugged.

Comment: @RichardHodges: No, it was not.  No one on the committee expressed interest in having it.  It is now too late to propose new features for C++17, however there is always a next standard (C++2x).  If you would like to propose it, I can help with the logistics of how to do that.  Proposals have the most success if you can present the proposal in person.