# Is this a valid way to upgrade a standard library lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, std

The C++ standard library lacks an `upgrade_lock` method, similar to what boost thread provides. But looking at the `adopt_lock` facilities, one might be tempted to do the following:

```cpp
// Declare a shared mutex
std::shared_mutex mtx;

// Create a reader lock 
std::shared_lock rlock(mtx);

// Other code and program logic ...

// Adopt the lock into a unique lock
std::unique_lock wlock(mtx, std::adopt_lock);
// Disassociate the reader lock to avoid doubly unlocking
rlock.unlock();
```

Is this valid / safe ? If not, is there a common practice on solving this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24334735/817643

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Standard:

> `unique_lock(mutex_type& m, adopt_lock_t);`
>
> Preconditions: The calling thread holds a *non-shared* lock on m.

So no.